# Type inferred by C++ auto

Tags: c++, auto

How does C++'s `auto` infer data types in case of `for` loops - from initialization, or from condition?

```cpp
long long n;
cin>>n;
for(auto i=1; i<=n; i++)
    cout << ((i * i) * ((i * i) - 1)) / 2 - 2 * (2 * (i - 1) * (i - 2)) << "\n";
```

Here, will `i` be an integer of `long long`? My code failed (probably due to overflow - negative values in output, n = 10000) when I used `auto` and passed when I used `long long`.

Comment: The same way it does for variables everywhere else. `1` is an integer literal, so `i` is an `int`

Comment: If you think a little it would become obvious that it is not possible to deduce `i` type from conditional part. What if it is `i - 100000000 > n`, what if `i` is not there at all?

Comment: If you want the actual rules, the book Effective Modern C++ lays it out very well.

Comment: `auto i = 1LL;` and then `i` will be `long long`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the simpler statement

```
auto i = 1;
```

it's obvious that `i` is an `int` type, since `1` is a literal of type `int`. That carries over to the declaration inside the `for` loop. C++ is remarkably self-consistent.

The type of the *stopping conditional* `i <= n` is a `bool` so that wouldn't be
much use to you.

If you want the index type to be the same as `n`, then use

```
for (decltype(n) i = 1;
```

at the start of the loop.

Comment: `auto i = n/n;` :)

Comment: @Slava: Prefer `n - n + 1` which is not a bad solution at all prior to C++11, though I'm not sure I've ever seen it in use.

Comment: That if you start from 0, OP wants to start from 1. Anyway when `for()` loop was created `auto` was not there and it is language gap there, on one side `auto` is should be used widely on another it does not fit `for()` loop well. And prior to `c++11` there was no `auto`

Comment: @Slava: No did you see the `+1` in my expression? (Granted, it was missing in the first edit.) Your expression breaks for `n == 0`. Mine doesn't. And it doesn't ever overflow ;-)

Comment: Yea I answered before you edited your comment. Anyway this was more like a joke, but `for()` does not really work well with `auto`

Comment: @Slava: Joke's on me: I'm now wrangling if mine breaks for `n` being LONG_LONG_MIN. My head hurts.

Comment: @Bathsheba clearly, we need to use `auto i = n ? n/n : n-n+1;`

Comment: @eerorika how about `auto i = true ? 1 : n;` ?

Comment: @Slava What if you wanted to deduce short?

Comment: @eerorika `short` will not work for other expressions either due to integral promotion. "In particular, arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable. This conversion always preserves the value."

Answer (score 1):

> How does C++'s auto infer data types in case of for loops

Same as all deduced variables: From the initialiser.

> Here, will i be a integer of long long?

It will be `int`.